# Send a adaptive card with data in python using 1.2 version

Tags: python, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

Based on the below, I have a card template and data separately as json.

https://adaptivecards.io/samples/FlightItinerary.html

But i am not sure how to send data through python for the below card. I cant find a documentation examples for template and data for python.
How do I send data to this card through python

```
    # code for adaptive card
    reply = MessageFactory.list([])
    reply.attachment_layout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.carousel
    reply.attachments.append(CardFactory.adaptive_card(LIST_JOB_CARD_CONTENT))
    await step_context.context.send_activity(reply)
```

```
LIST_JOB_CARD_CONTENT ={
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.2",
"body": [
{
"type": "ColumnSet",
"columns": [
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "stretch",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "Job Number",
"size": "Small",
"weight": "Bolder",
"color": "Accent"
}
]
},
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "stretch",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "Job Status",
"fontType": "Default",
"size": "Small",
"color": "Accent",
"weight": "Bolder",
"horizontalAlignment": "Center"
}
]
},
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "stretch",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "Design Reference",
"weight": "Bolder",
"color": "Accent",
"size": "Small",
"horizontalAlignment": "Right"
}
]
}
],
"style": "default",
"spacing": "Small",
"horizontalAlignment": "Center",
"height": "stretch",
"minHeight": "5px"
},
{
"type": "ColumnSet",
"columns": [
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "stretch",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "${$root.JobNumber}",
"size": "Medium",
"color": "Good",
"weight": "Bolder"
}
]
},
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "stretch",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "${$root.jobStatus}",
"weight": "Bolder",
"color": "Attention",
"size": "Medium",
"horizontalAlignment": "Center"
}
]
},
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "stretch",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "${$root.DesignReference}",
"size": "Medium",
"weight": "Bolder",
"color": "Good",
"horizontalAlignment": "Center"
}
]
}
],
"style": "default",
"spacing": "Small",
"horizontalAlignment": "Center",
"height": "stretch"
},
{
"type": "ColumnSet",
"columns": [
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "250px",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "Customer Name",
"size": "Medium",
"weight": "Bolder",
"color": "Accent",
"horizontalAlignment": "Center",
"spacing": "Medium"
}
],
"backgroundImage": {
"horizontalAlignment": "Center"
},
"spacing": "Small"
},
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "stretch",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "Promotion",
"horizontalAlignment": "Center",
"size": "Medium",
"weight": "Bolder",
"color": "Accent"
}
]
}
],
"id": "CustomerName"
},
{
"type": "ColumnSet",
"columns": [
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "250px",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"horizontalAlignment": "Center",
"text": "${$root.CustomerName}",
"wrap": True,
"size": "Medium",
"fontType": "Monospace",
"color": "Good",
"weight": "Lighter"
}
]
},
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "stretch",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "${$root.Promotion}",
"horizontalAlignment": "Center",
"fontType": "Monospace",
"size": "Medium",
"color": "Good"
}
]
}
]
},
{
"type": "ColumnSet",
"columns": [
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "50px",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "Brand->",
"size": "Small",
"weight": "Bolder",
"color": "Accent"
}
]
},
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "stretch",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "${$root.Brand}",
"id": "brand",
"wrap": True,
"size": "Medium",
"color": "Warning",
"horizontalAlignment": "Right"
}
]
}
]
},
{
"type": "ColumnSet",
"columns": [
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "100px",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "RangeName->",
"fontType": "Default",
"size": "Small",
"weight": "Bolder",
"color": "Accent"
}
]
},
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "stretch",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "${$root.RangeName}",
"size": "Medium",
"color": "Warning",
"horizontalAlignment": "Right"
}
]
}
]
},
{
"type": "ColumnSet",
"columns": [
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "60px",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "Variety->",
"size": "Small",
"weight": "Bolder",
"color": "Accent"
}
]
},
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "stretch",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "${$root.Variety}",
"horizontalAlignment": "Right",
"size": "Medium",
"color": "Warning"
}
]
}
]
}
]
}



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkjO4.png
```

Comment: Is this not supported in python ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find any way to pass in data to the JSON template using the Python SDK. However, I was able to solve this problem doing the following:

1. In your `.json` file add tags (`${key_name}`) wherever you want to add a value passed in from python:

```
{
    "text": "${name}"
}
```

2. Create a function that receives a dict (parsed json) and a dict with the `key_name`,`value` pairs you want to insert in the `.json` file:

```
def replace(template: dict, data:dict):
        import re
        str_temp = str(template)
        for key in data:
            pattern = "\${"+key+"}"
            str_temp = re.sub(pattern, str(data[key]),str_temp)        
        return eval(str_temp)
```

3. Use the function to replace all tags in the `.json` file:

```
def create_adaptive_card_attachment(self):
        # read the .json file
        relative_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        path = os.path.join(relative_path, "../cards/my_card.json")
        with open(path) as in_file:
            card_template = json.load(in_file)
        template_data = {"name":"Obi-Wan"}
        card =replace(card_template,template_data)
        
        return Attachment(
            content_type="application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive", content=card
        )
```

4. Send the card to the user:

```
card = self.create_adaptive_card_attachment()
            response = MessageFactory.attachment(card)
            await step_context.context.send_activity(response)
```

Comment: With the replace method you have suggested, we cannot add complex data into the template. Example I am not able to add a dict of choices for Input.ChoiceSet

Answer (score 0):

Create your adaptive card in a json file (ie FlightItenerary.json), then use something like the following:

```
import json
import os
import random

from botbuilder.core import ActivityHandler, TurnContext, CardFactory
from botbuilder.schema import ChannelAccount, Attachment, Activity, ActivityTypes

CARDS = [
    "resources/FlightItineraryCard.json"
]


class AdaptiveCardsBot(ActivityHandler):

    async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        message = Activity(
            text="Here is an Adaptive Card:",
            type=ActivityTypes.message,
            attachments=[self._create_adaptive_card_attachment()],
        )

        await turn_context.send_activity(message)

    def _create_adaptive_card_attachment(self) -> Attachment:
        card_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), CARDS[0])
        with open(card_path, "rb") as in_file:
            card_data = json.load(in_file)

        return CardFactory.adaptive_card(card_data)
```

This is altered code from the official bot framework sample [07. Using Adaptive Cards](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/python/07.using-adaptive-cards)

Comment: I know this works perfectly fine if the data is already in the json. But Ms Bot services released new adaptive cards with templates and json separately. Merging of data with template could be done at the front end

Comment: I'll look into this and update my answer accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

```py
def replace(template: dict, data:dict):
        import re
        str_temp = json.dumps(template)
        for key in data:
            pattern = "\${"+key+"}"
            str_temp = re.sub(pattern, str(data[key]),str_temp)        
        return json.loads(str_temp)
```

I suggest using Dharman's answer, but please be mindful of using eval! This can be dangerous if you let your templated JSON depend on some form of user input. The function above solves this by first dumping the template into a JSON string (instead of doing a string() conversion yourself) and then properly re-converting it into a JSON object later with json.loads.